# Need to match a unique string from a file, then remove the entire encapsulated text

Tags: regex, sed, awk

Good Day Everyone,

I'm currently trying to write a routine that will examine a file for a particular unique string, then delete the entire encapsulated text as follows:

```
define service{
    use                     generic-service,srv-pnp
    host_name               MEVIE.COM
    service_description     NSClient++ Version
    check_command           check_nt!CLIENTVERSION
    }
```

There's many instances of `define service { ... }` in the file.  So I can't just search on define service, I have to search on the unique string then delete the entire `define service { ... }` encapsulation.

For example:

- Find the string "NSClient++ Version" in the file...
- Delete EVERYTHING within `define service{ .... }`
- Delete `define service { .... }` tags as well.

I really hope my goal is clear.

I've tried: `sed -n '/NSClient+++ Version/{H;g;p};H' MEVIE.bak|tail -n5 > mevie.fil` .. it returns everything except the last '}'

Comment: Can there be `{}` nesting inside `define service`?

Comment: @nhahtdh - No, there will be no nested {}

Comment: Google for "sed multi-line"

Comment: @user1883592 - No, do NOT google for "sed multi-line" unless it's to get a chuckle at the syntax. sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line but for any other text manipulation needs you should use awk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way using `sed`. Run like:

```
sed -f script.sed file
```

Contents of `script.sed`:

```
:t
/define service{/ , /}/ {
    /}/! {
        $! {
            N;
            bt
        }
    }
    /NSClient++ Version/d;
}
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
sed ':t /define service{/ , /}/ { /}/! { $! { N; bt } }; /NSClient++ Version/d }' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
/^define service{/ { inBlock = 1; block = "" }

inBlock {
   block = block $0 ORS
   if (/}/) {
      if (block !~ /NSClient\+\+ Version/)
         printf "%s",block
      inBlock = 0
   }
   next
}

{ print }
' file
```

Comment: that is awesome Ed.. I will try it out shortly.  Keep you in the loop

Answer (score 0):

There are shorter solution, but I used to do it this way:

```
awk '/^define service/ {
  if ( $0 ~ "}" ) {
    block=$0
  } else {
    block=$0
    while ( block !~ "}" ) {
      getline nl
      block=block "\n" nl      
    }
  }
  if ( block !~ "NSClient\\+\\+ Version" ) { print block } 
}' INPUTFILE > OUTPUTFILE
```

[See here in action](http://ideone.com/q2OAlJ).

1. on every starting (`define...`) line check if it contains `}`, and if so, save the line as `block`
2. else read until the next line with `}` and add the lines to `block`
3. finally check if we want to print it out

Comment: The above will fail in various ways given various input files and will be difficult to enhance in future, all courtesy of getline. See http://awk.info/?tip/getline. It also won't print the file contents between blocks and is unnecessarily using a string RE in the RE comparison, hence the need to escape the "+"s twice.

Answer (score 0):

One way with perl:

```
perl -0pe 's/define service[ \t]*\{[^{}]*?NSClient\+\+[ \t]+Version[^{}]*?\}//gs' filename
```